# Cannot read property 'query' of undefined en NodeJs

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, router

empiezo con Node y estoy viendo la manera para crear un api para consultas a la db, todo bien logre conectar la db y levantar, pero ahora me enfrento con esto

> Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

tengo un archivo llamado config.js

```
const mssql = require('mssql')

const config = {
    server: '###',
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'sa',
            password: '######',
        },
    },
    options: {
        database: 'SQLPRUEBAS',
        encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbort: false
        
    },
};

const poolPromise = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config)

module.exports = poolPromise;
```

teste antes y me manda la conexion correcta
luego cuando quiero ejecutar el query para llamar a los datos es cuando me manda el error

```
var pool = require('../data/config').pool;

// Router
const router = app => {
    app.get('/', (request, response) => {
        response.send({
            message: 'blah blah blah'
        });
    });

    app.get('/users', (request, response) => {
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM Usuarios', (error, result) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            response.send(result);
        });
    });
}


module.exports = router;
```

este es en mi archivo router

si estoy usando

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
}));
```

pero no logro hacerlo funcionar
alguna idea

Answer (score 0):

El export que estás usando se llama `poolPromise`; `pool` no existe. Me parece que lo correcto sería:

```
var poolPromise = require('../data/config').poolPromise;
```

Y luego en el código debajo hay que hacer un `await`:

```
const pool = await poolPromise
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, por contestar

He agregado el code pero sigue mandando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

en tu archivo de rutas estas llamando mal a tu archivo config, fijate que el nombre que le asignaste a el es:

`module.exports = poolPromise;`

deberias llamarlo entonces:

`const poolPromise = require('../data/config').poolPromise;`